# Переписать приложение со spring boot на spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jwt

Есть работающие приложения на spring boot.
Нужно их перенести в голый spring mvc.
Например есть https://github.com/kazakovav/spring-boot-keycloak/tree/main/demo-keycloak-resource
Как смог его на mvc перенес https://github.com/stydent/demo-keycloak-resource-byKazakov-mvc/, но там то одного бина, то другого не хватает.
В частности сейчас уткнулся в No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с mvc прочитав статью https://mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/ . Понял что можно конфигурировать как в xml так и на java .

С spring mvc чуть больше страданий при запуске, много настроек надо написать.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]